# Time interval (in ms) from BPM (Midi tempo)

Tags: time, business-process-management, tempo

Does anybody know formula ?

I tried following:
   1000 / ((BPM * 24) / 60).
But seems not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think my answer is MIDI-specific, but to convert beats-per-minute to ms-per-beat, would this work?

```
ms_per_beat = 1000 * 60 / bpm
```

In other words, I think you have an extra "24" in there.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply:

```
Time of 1 beat in ms = 1000 * 60 / BPM = 60000 / BPM
```

Comment: Will - doesn't this put units of time on the bottom, when @user1195202 is requesting they show up on the top?

Comment: You're absolutely right... in my haste I wrote it the wrong way round! I'll edit it to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your formula is assuming data coming from a standard midi file, where tempo is expressed in terms of ticks, where there are 24 ticks per quarter note. It's not giving you ms per beat, it's giving you ms per tick.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on [converting BPM to MS](http://nickfever.com/music/blog/2014/how-to-calculate-reverb-and-delay-times)

and I made an online app called a [Delay Time Calculator](http://nickfever.com/music/delay-calculator) that does just that including giving you dotted and triplet notes